# see all extenders and custom bindings for observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

Is it possible to see all extenders and bindings attached to an observable within Knockout JS?

Sample View Model:

```
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;

  self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({required: "Please enter a name",
                                           logChange: "first name" });

  self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required:true});

}
```

I am also using several custom bindingHandlers including the [Knockout X-Editable Plugin](https://github.com/brianchance/knockout-x-editable) in addition to the [KO Validation Plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)

Sample Multi-Page View:

```
  <!--Screen 1 -->
  <input data-bind="value:firstName"/>

   ....

  <!--Screen 2 -->
  <span data-bind="editable:firstName"></span>
```

A. Is there a way to query `self.firstName()` and get a list of all of the extenders?

`{required: "Please enter a name", logChange: "first name" }`

B. Is there another query that I can run to get all of the bindings handlers that depend upon this observable? Can this be returned as DOM elements?

Basically I am trying to display validation errors for imported data, but I want to append them below `<span data-bind="editable"/>` if I am on the 2nd view.

This is simple enough when validating each input individually, but it's getting complicated when using `ko.validation.group(viewModel)`. Even if I iterate over every error, I'm not seeing how I can relate them with the original observable that threw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom binding you can use

```
<span data-bind="validationMessage: myObservable"></span>
```

If that is not enough then you have to get creative :D

There is no generic way of seeing all extenders on a observable. KO validation adds a few functions and observables to the extended observable that you can use

- clearError
- error
- isValid
- isValidating
- rules
- setError

You need to create a custom binding to be able to see all bindings attached to a element. This is not a bad thing, its bad practice to have dependencies to the View from the ViewModel. From your custom binding init or update function you have a allBindingsAccessor

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    init: function(element, accessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
       var valueAttachedToCheckedBinding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've known about the validationMessage binding, but I was wondering if there was another way for me to just grab the message and manipulate it myself when working with a validatedObservable (validation group). If this returns an array of errors, which are observables themselves, is there a function I can call on each error to find the parent?

Comment: No, sadly the only one knowing the structure of the viewmodel is the bindingcontext