# Testing Knockout Extenders with Qunit

Tags: knockout.js, qunit, chutzpah

I am trying to write a qUnit test for the below Knockout extender. I seem to be going down slightly the wrong path and any tips on how to correct my unit test would be appreciated.

```
ko.extenders.AddItems = function (array, items)
{
    var mutated = false;
    var underlyingArray = array();
    for (var $i2 = 0, $l2 = items.length, item = items[$i2]; $i2 < $l2; $i2++, item = items[$i2])
    {
        underlyingArray.push(item);
        mutated = true;
    }
    if (mutated)
    {
        ko.extenders.ArrayHasMutated(array);
    }
};
```

Unit Test:

```
test("RemoveItemsTest", function () {

    var startArray = new Array();
    startArray[0] = "1";
    startArray[1] = "2";
    startArray[2] = "3";

    var remArray = new Array();
    remArray[0] = "2";

    var compareArray = new Array();
    compareArray[0] = "1";
    compareArray[2] = "3";


    ko.extenders.RemoveItems(startArray, remArray);

    equal(startArray, compareArray);


});
```

Comment: test("RemoveItemsTest", function () {


    var startArray = ko.observableArray();    // Initially an empty array
    startArray.push('1');
    startArray.push('2');
    startArray.push('3');


    var remArray = new Array();
    remArray[0] = "2";

    var compareArray = ko.observableArray();
    compareArray.push('1');
    compareArray.push('3');


    ko.extenders.RemoveItems(startArray, remArray);

    equal(startArray.value, compareArray.value);


});

Comment: The `RemoveItemsTest` is for a completely different extender. How is that *"going down slightly the wrong path"*?

Comment: Hey @user2734248, welcome to SO! You can (and probably should) edit your question and inline your comment, and remove (delete) the comment afterwards. In addition, please update your question following Tomalak's comment (your two snippets are about different things). If you update your question substantially it'll get bumped too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [see all extenders and custom bindings for observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076547/see-all-extenders-and-custom-bindings-for-observable)